# What would cause the drop event to not fire in jquery.fileupload.js?

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I've noticed that within jquery.fileupload.js, the widget specifies the drop zone to be the entire document by default.

```
options: {
    // The drop target element(s), by the default the complete document.
    // Set to null to disable drag & drop support:
    dropZone: $(document)
}
```

And that the specified drop zone element has the following event handlers attached to it.

```
_initEventHandlers: function () {
    if (this._isXHRUpload(this.options)) {

        this._on(this.options.dropZone, { 
            dragover: this._onDragOver, 
            drop: this._onDrop, 
            // event.preventDefault() on dragenter is required for IE10+:
            dragenter: this._onDragEnter,
            // dragleave is not required, but added for completeness:
            dragleave: this._onDragLeave
        });
        this._on(this.options.pasteZone, {
            paste: this._onPaste
        });
    }
```

I have a site where the drop event handler isn't being called whenever a file is dropped onto the page. The dragover event fires but not the drop event. 
**Question:**
Does anyone have any idea what would be preventing the drop event from firing?

I should note that there is another script where the widget properties are being set. In that script, the add callback is successfully invoked when files are dropped only onto the file input element.

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({ 
    url: url,
    formData: {'_authenticator': $('#_authenticator').val()},
    dataType: 'json',
    autoUpload: false,
    maxChunkSize: parseInt($('#chunksize').attr('data'))
}).on('fileuploadadd', function (e, data) {
    // add file event code
}
```

I don't think any of this custom code would necessarily prevent the dropzone's events from firing but I would like to hear anyone's thoughts.

Thank you.